# Allowing SSH from selected IP through a definite interface

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, firewalld

I'm Using Ubuntu 18.04 and I have two different interfaces in a single card.

Let's suppose that the IP's of said interfaces are `1.1.1.1` & `2.2.2.2`

I want that anyone can connect with ssh through `1.1.1.1`, but only a list of  selected IPs to connect through `2.2.2.2`

How can I do that?

Comment: You typically [configure a firewall](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html)

Answer (score 1):

Hello Amin I will try to help you achieve what you want:

I understand you got 2 interfaces 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2 and you need 1.1.1.1 to be public and 2.2.2.2 to be private with a Whitelist of IP's.

Follow this steps and I think you will be able to do it:

1. Open you sshd_config file (use nano if you're a **vi noob**)

> sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config

2. Add the following lines to the config file

> ListenAddress 1.1.1.1
>
> ListenAddress 2.2.2.2

3. Save and close the file
4. Restart the sshd daemon

> sudo /etc/init.d/sshd restart OR sudo service sshd restart

5. Check that SSH is listening to the ports you just defined

> netstat -tulpn | grep :22

6. Use Ubuntu's default Uncomplicated firewall to deny all traffic to your 2.2.2.2 interface

> sudo ufw deny from any to 2.2.2.2 port 22

7. Whitelist your IP and the ones you want to be able to access 2.2.2.2

> sudo ufw allow in from 123.123.221.1 to 2.2.2.2 port 22

-

I think this is what you wanted, have a nice day!

Comment: By default sshd will already listen on all interfaces and any ip-address making steps 1-5 redundant.

Comment: Sorry HbBrujin, You mean steps 1 though 5 or just step 5?

But yes it's a little redundant but it will work for him nevertheless

Comment: Steps one through five are redundant, by default `ss -tulpn` or `netstat -tulpn` will show sshd listening to all local IPv4 addresses with `0.0.0.0:22` and to all local IPv6 addresses with `:::22` - In most default configurations your addition to the sshd_config file will ensure that sshd listens on the ip-addresses 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2 but but also will result that sshd will stop listening on any other ip-addresses that are configured on the system, such as localhost.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying HB, let's hope OP also reads your comment.

Also OP if you're reading this, I really recommend you use a search engine and look for "SSH Server Best Practices"